# Is there an API to get the tenant ID for a give name?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk-.net

If i have a tenant name such as "contoso.onmicrosoft.com" can i get the tenantID using an API call?
I have already checked the API for Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceGroup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the name of the tenant you are logged into by calling

`https://management.azure.com/tenants?$skiptoken={skiptoken}&api-version={api-version}`

see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790536.aspx) for details 
This will give you a list of all tenants that you authorized for.

This is actually listed under 'Tenants' rather than resource groups.

Comment: sorry Michael. I don't need the subscriptions. I need a tenant-name to tenant-ID call

Comment: apologies, I misread the question! (or didn't pay enough attention)

Answer (score 6):

You can simply call `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantDomain/.well-known/openid-configuration` and get the tenant id from there. Just parse the JSON it returns and get the tenant id from it - for example from `issuer`.

Full info can be found [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/18/from-domain-to-tenantid/).

The call doesn't have to be authenticated so it is very simple to call.

Answer (score 0):

Te easiest way to get tenantID is to find it in Azure portal. Please click  -> APPLICATION -> VIEW ENDPOINT. like the following screenshot:
[image]

If you want to use C# to get the tenant ID from the name. Please try to get the JWT token first (use the user under the "contoso.onmicrosoft.com" to sign in). The JWT token will contain tid. "tid" means tenant id. Refer to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-token-and-claims/) for more details.
Then we can use the following code to get the tenant id:

```html
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtToken);
var oid = token.Claims.FirstOrDefault(m=>m.Type == "tid").Value;
```